# Date issue while extracting from mysql in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a date column in my mysql db which stores

```
1999-03-30
```

as  the date.

Using webservices when i extract the value by following code

```
DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DOB"]),
```

The output on the screen is

```
/Date(922732200000)/
```

How to get 1999-03-30 and what is this value /Date(922732200000)/...

Comment: It is the format javaScript serialier uses for DateTime. try this: `var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(DateTime.Now)`

Comment: plz tell me in context of .net as js is not used in code anywhere

Comment: It is in the context of .Net. Make your own search `restfull webservices json datetime` or similar

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle dates in mysql is to use UNIX TIMESTAMP to store and retrieve dates.
For example:

The query for inserting date should be:

```
string query="insert into myTable(name,date) values ("StackOverflow",unix_timestamp('yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss')";
```

eg. If you want to enter the current datetime, this query can be re-Written as:

```
string query="insert into myTable(name,date) values ("StackOverflow",unix_timestamp(current_timestamp)";
```

and when you retrive the data from your table, the query should be:

```
string queryToretrivedata="select name, from_unixtime(date) as DOB from myTable";
```

While the MySqlreader reads the data, the statement in your function should be:

```
DateTime DOB= Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DOB"].ToString());
```

Also, if you want to convert this dateTime into string you can use

```
string DateInString==DOB.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); //For 24 hour Format

string DateInString==DOB.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt"); //For 12 Hour format
```